# Themekit, Browsersync and Shopify

Tags: themes, shopify, browser-sync

I have a problem about themekit and browsersync with Shopify. I have a package.json with this code in my scripts. However, the very first time I make changes to my code, the browser does not show the changes, if I manually refresh it will. Every other time browsersync works fine. I am wondering if there’s anything wrong with the command.

```
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "theme": "theme watch --allow-live --notify=themeWatchNotify",
        "sync": "browser-sync start --proxy 'https://example.myshopify.com/' --files 'themeWatchNotify' --config bs-config.js"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--reload-delay 1000`.

There is an issue with the themekit notify, where it seems that it doesn't update the file when it's uploaded, but rather when the upload is started.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I've tried adding a --reload-delay 1000 and it still doesn't work for the first time. I also have a bs-config.js, not sure if there's something in there that's stopping it from doing it the first time

Comment: https://github.com/Shopify/themekit/issues/773 The devs have discussed it on here that they have fixed the delay time. Adding a reload time of 2000 works, but still a pain

Comment: @TarinChance no other choice. I have a custom webpack setup around themekit and the delay is what works for now.